# Based on this, who am I?

Tags: riddle

> I was born from your deepest emotions.
>   I was cared for as your most valuable treasure,
>   then I left you, but you kept running after me.
>   If you let me go, you will never truly live again,
>   but if you catch me, you will die.

**So, who am I?**

Comment: Welcome to puzzling! I tidied your question up a bit for you, if you click 'edit' you can see the formatting I used for future reference. Also you can click on a tag to see it's info and whether it's relevant. See the [tour](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour) for more information. Good luck!

Comment: So, uh, what's the answer? @Iry-Hor

Comment: I don't thing that they would give the answer like that

Comment: Can we assume that the 'you' in this riddle is the reader (i.e. a human being), or could 'you' refer to a 3rd party object?

Comment: Has a correct answer been given?  If so, please click the checkmark to Accept it.  If not, you may want to give some feedback on the answers attempted thus far, and/or offer a hint, as forward progress seems to have stopped.

Comment: Hey there @Iry-Hor, was my answer correct? If not, mind telling me it's not right? And then providing another hint or just the answer??

Answer (score 3):

You're:

> a dog.

I was born from your deepest emotions

> Most children dream of getting a dog, and, without love yet, their deepest emotions are dreams.

I was cared as your most valuable treasure, then I left you

> If you're a child with a dog, you love that dog. Yet dogs run away.

but you kept running after me

> of course you ran after that dog you loved, that ran away, you want it back.

if you let me go, you will never truly live again

> if you don't catch that dog, you'll be sad the rest of your life, never being truly happy again, feeling like it's your fault.

but if you catch me, you will die

> the dog, of course, didn't run away, it was released by the child's dad because it had rabies, and if the child ever caught up with the dog, the dog (meaner than ever after being expelled by the father) would take its aggression out on the child, biting and then killing it.

Comment: ... well that took quite a turn

Comment: @Will you didn't see all along that the dog would have rabies? :))

Comment: I apologize, for this failure of mine, you used your most valuable right, to give me your take on the aspects of life, but still, i will give you a hint, or perhaps a sign, to use on the most dangerous times, well, i must tell you, here it lies.

Answer (score 1):

You're:

> Happiness.

I was born from your deepest emotions

> True it's born out  of your deepest emotions.

I was cared as your most valuable treasure, then I left you

> It's most valuable treasure and you know it's value when it leaves you for a reason.

but you kept running after me

> You spend all your life running after happiness.

if you let me go, you will never truly live again

> If you let happiness go for some reason you will be living but not truly.

but if you catch me, you will die

> And according to most of the holy scriptures real happiness lies in death so you get eternal happiness as you die.

Comment: you found a path, and i congratulate you for that, but there is a way still hidden in the maze, this hint may save your life, or at least give you a flashlight.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as it doesnt have an answer yet, Let me try as well

You're

> Time

I was born from your deepest emotions.

> Fear that your time is near

I was cared for as your most valuable treasure,

> Time is a kind of treasure as you can only experience it once in a lifetime

then I left you, but you kept running after me.

> Whatever you do, Time will always pass away.
>  Yet we always trying to catch him.

If you let me go, you will never truly live again,

> If you cant keep up with the way things are going,
>  You will find it hard to socialize.

but if you catch me, you will die.

> Well... if your time's up. you will die.

Answer (score -1):

My guess:

> a child who has died... maybe? I think it matches pretty well with the first 2 and a half lines

I was born from your deepest emotions

> Literally born from the parent, and they are very emotionally attached

I was cared as your most valuable treasure, then I left you

> A child is a parent's 'most valuable treasure', and then they died

but you kept running after me

> The parent wants the child back

if you let me go, you will never truly live again

> The parent will be extremely miserable

but if you catch me, you will die

> Not sure... maybe the child was killed by like a serial killer and if the parent finds them they die as well?

I feel like my answer is kind of off track, but the first two and a half lines do match really well.

Comment: You have reached a point, surely indeed, but there is one thing still left to see, read this again and you will see my hint.